# Is there a common way of getting the uploaded file across multiple Python frameworks?

Tags: python, wsgi

Is there a common way of getting the uploaded files in Python just like $_FILES is in PHP?

In Django there is `request.FILES['fieldid']`, in Pyramid `request.POST['fieldid']`, while in Flask `request.files['fieldid']`. And all these return a different type of object. However, is there a generic way of getting that in all 3 frameworks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think  the answer is no! Because for example in django, the HttpRequest class which has FILES attribute, is a dictionary and is populated by other parts of framework. So this object is created and built by django and only inherited from object class so it is just a dictionary.

```
class HttpRequest(object):
    """A basic HTTP request."""

    # The encoding used in GET/POST dicts. None means use default setting.
    _encoding = None
    _upload_handlers = []

    def __init__(self):
        # WARNING: The `WSGIRequest` subclass doesn't call `super`.
        # Any variable assignment made here should also happen in
        # `WSGIRequest.__init__()`.

        self.GET = QueryDict(mutable=True)
        self.POST = QueryDict(mutable=True)
        self.COOKIES = {}
        self.META = {}
        self.FILES = MultiValueDict()

        self.path = ''
        self.path_info = ''
        self.method = None
        self.resolver_match = None
        self._post_parse_error = False
        self.content_type = None
        self.content_params = None
```

You can see full source code here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/http/request/#HttpRequest